# Sort a List of date intervals using the first date

Tags: r

How can I sort a list of date intervals of the form:

```
ll <- list(c('2015-03-01','2015-03-10'), c('2015-02-01','2015-02-10'),c('2015-01-01','2015-01-10'))
```

by the first date, to get:

```
list(c('2015-01-01','2015-01-10'), c('2015-02-01','2015-02-10'),c('2015-03-01','2015-03-10'))
```

Comment: @akrun tks for the advise. I never accept in the first day, in order to motivate others to participate. And in my only old question, I have made the response myself, and I don't like to accept my own answer (or should I?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
ll[order(sapply(ll, FUN = function(x) x[1]))]
[[1]]
[1] "2015-01-01" "2015-01-10"

[[2]]
[1] "2015-02-01" "2015-02-10"

[[3]]
[1] "2015-03-01" "2015-03-10"
```

and from Akrun's comment

```
ll[order(sapply(ll, `[[`, 1))]
```